# UK + Dutch Citizen - EHIC card rights in Germany

Tags: ehic

I am a UK citizen and have just also acquired Dutch citizenship. It seems that after Brexit on 31.12.20 that the EHIC services will probably no longer be available for UK citizens in Europe.
I am intending to travel to Germany in January 2021. Would I be covered by the EHIC as a Dutch citizen? I have tried to research this and the wording I have found states that a Dutch citizen OR resident would be covered by the EHIC. However I am concerned that to qualify for EHIC as a Dutch citizen you would need a Dutch residential address and Dutch health insurance, which I do not have.

Comment: What wording have you found saying that a Dutch citizen or resident would be covered?  It seems incorrect.  It would be easier to say that with confidence if we knew its source.

Comment: It was on one of the "official" websites, I don't remember now which one, but it is not important now as it seems to be clear that you need to be a resident and have health insurance from the same country as your permanent residence, and that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your concern is well-founded. You need to be affiliated to the statutory healthcare system in another EU member state to be covered by the EHIC system. This means that citizenship as such is irrelevant, you really need to reside in the EU (even if you're not an EU citizen).

That also means that it will still be possible for British citizens to get a EHIC, *provided they reside in the EU* (whether under the transition regime from the withdrawal agreement or as a third-country national outside of EU law).

Comment: I would underscore the principle (by mentioning if explicitly) that the system is based on residence rather than citizenship.  Even a third-country national resident in the Netherlands can benefit from EHIC in Germany, and a Dutch national resident outside the EU cannot, whether that residence is in the UK (after the UK stops participating) or elsewhere.

Comment: @phoog Good point, I tried to stress it further. I was a bit unsure how to phrase it because coverage does not stem from residence as such but really from affiliation to the local system. For example, in Germany, if you choose to go for a private insurance plan (that's the case for about 10% of the population), I think that you are not part of the system.

Comment: Thanks you everyone for your comments and advice, much appreciated

Comment: @Relaxed That is correct. A friend of mine is privately insured and his card as no EHIC markings printed on the back of his card. Future British **National Health** cards probably won't have them either.

Comment: @phoog To be more precise: You have to be a **member** of an heath system organization that is part of the EHIC system.